# The Use of Ordinals and Cardinals in Recursive Proofs

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, ordinals, universal-algebra

I'm reading something on ordinal numbers and I have a probably silly doubt.

Well, let $Z:=\{x_i: \, i \in I\}$ be a subset of a given set $X$. Define in $X$ a sequence $Y_\alpha=\Gamma(Y_{\alpha-1})$ when $\alpha$ is non limit and $Y_\alpha=\bigcup\limits_{\beta <\alpha} \Gamma(Y_\beta)$ (here $\Gamma$ is a given extensive function on the powerset of $X$). In this way, I obtain an increasing sequence $Y_0 \subseteq Y_1 \subseteq \dots \subseteq Y_{\omega} \subseteq ...$ Denote by $Y$ the corresponding union and suppose that $Z \subseteq Y$. By Bergman - An Invitation to General Algebra [prop. 5.5.4 (ii)] "The union of any set of ordinals is an ordinal". Thus, there exists an ordinal $\beta$ such that $Z \subseteq Y_\beta$.

Now, in order to make more concrete my request, I will consider the following situation: suppose that the elements $z,w$ are pairs of subsets of a given ground set $\Omega$ and $X=\mathcal{P}(\Omega) \times \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$. This means that the subsets $Y_\alpha$ are collections of pairs of subsets of $\Omega$. I assume that if $z=(A,B)$ and $w=(C,B)$, then the pair $(A \cup C,B)$ is the result of an operation $\times$ defined between $z$ and $w$.

At this point, suppose that if $z,w \in Y_\gamma$, then the result of $z \times w \in \Gamma(Y_\gamma)=Y_{\gamma+1}$.
.
My question is: if the members of $Z$ are pairs $(A_z,B)$ with the second component given by the same subset $B$, when I apply the operation on all the elements of $Z$ I get a pair $(\bigcup\limits_{z \in Z} A_z, B)$. Does the resulting pair belong to $\bigcup Y_\alpha$?

Comment: What does it mean to multiply "all the elements of $Z$"? If $Z$ is infinite your operation is not binary anymore. (Even in the case of $\Bbb R$ and addition there is no reason to expect infinite sums to produce a real numbers. And that's "the nice" case.)

Comment: In my case, the elements $z$ and $w$ may be seen as subsets and the operation at issue is $\bigcup$

Comment: I edited my question in a slightly different way with respect tho the previous comment

Comment: There are a lot of extraneous details in your question that make it hard to understand. I think it boils down to the following: Let $(Y_\gamma)$ be a continuous increasing sequence of collections of subsets of $\Omega$, indexed by the ordinals, and let $Y = \bigcup_{\gamma}Y_{\gamma}$. Let $(A_z)_{z\in Z}$ be a family of subsets of $\Omega$. Assume that (1) for all $z\in Z$, there is some $\gamma$ such that $A_z\in Y_\gamma$, and (2) if $A_z$ and $A_{z'}$ are in $Y_\gamma$, then $A_z\cup A_{z'}\in Y_{\gamma+1}$. Does it follow that $\bigcup_{z\in Z} A_z\in Y$?

Comment: The answer is no: For example, if every $Y_\gamma$ contains only finite subsets of $\Omega$, then $Y$ contains only finite subsets of $\Omega$. Further, if all the $A_z$ are finite, it's possible to satisfy (1) and (2), but have $\bigcup_{z\in Z} A_z$ infinite. If this answers your question, I can turn it into an official answer. If not, how does your setup differ substantially from my simplified version?

Comment: Yes, it is the answer. I did the example with pairs, but yours works well and sounds better. I'm extremely thankful to you

Comment: @TheWanderer I've turned my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of your question, which I think should settle your confusion.

Let $(Y_\gamma)_{\gamma\in\mathrm{Ord}}$ be a continuous increasing sequence of collections of subsets of $\Omega$, indexed by the ordinals, and let $(A_z)_{z\in Z}$ be a family of subsets of $\Omega$.

Assume that (1) for all $z\in Z$, there is some $\gamma$ such that $A_z\in Y_\gamma$, and (2) if $A_z$ and $A_{z'}$ are in $Y_\gamma$, then $A_z\cup A_{z'}\in Y_{\gamma+1}$.

Does it follow that $\bigcup_{z\in Z} A_z\in \bigcup_{\gamma\in \mathrm{Ord}}Y_\gamma$?

The answer is no: For example, take $\Omega = \mathbb{N}$, $Y_\gamma = \mathcal{P}_{\mathrm{fin}}(\mathbb{N}) = \{B\subseteq \mathbb{N}\mid B\text{ is finite}\}$ for all $\gamma$, so $(Y_\gamma)_{\gamma\in \mathrm{Ord}}$ is the constant sequence and $\bigcup_{\gamma\in \mathrm{Ord}} Y_\gamma = \mathcal{P}_{\mathrm{fin}}(\mathbb{N})$. Let $Z = \mathbb{N}$, and define $A_n = \{n\}$ for all $n$.  Then (1) and (2) are satisfied, since $A_n\in Y_\gamma$ and $A_n\cup A_m\in Y_\gamma$ for all $n,m\in \mathbb{N}$ and all $\gamma$. But $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} A_n = \mathbb{N}\notin \mathcal{P}_{\mathrm{fin}}(\mathbb{N})$.

The point is that the closure condition (2) ensures that any *finite* union of the $A_z$ is in some $Y_\gamma$, but there's no reason to expect that this extends to *infinite* unions.

Comment: We are using ordinals here because they are “canonical” well orders, but are canonical well orders really needed? couldn’t everything be phrased in terms of “large enough” well ordered sets(given by Hartogs lemma). This makes me wonder if ordinals are really needed or just a convenience? Same for cardinals,  why do we need to have a formal ordinal definition, when it seems we could just work in terms of injections and bijections on sets… A bit of of topic but given these things are studied so deeply I think it deserves an answer!

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku You've asked a *very* general question in a comment to my answer, which is about a very specific problem. I don't think this comments section is a good place to try to answer your question. Why don't you ask it as its own question?

Comment: Thanks, I have asked it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4660421/why-do-we-need-canonical-well-orders

Comment: I received a few upvotes, so it seems this question is common among non-experts, it would be great if you could provide an expert answer!

Comment: Given that my question got no answer, I guess ordinals are useless after all :-( this is kind of sad given how deeply they are studied.

Comment: ...and even if "convenience" is the answer? Is there a reason why set-theorists find Von-Neumann ordinals so convenient?

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku I don't know why you're continuing to post in the comments here. I think your question is a good one, and if I had a good answer for you - and time to write one right now - I would. But I'm going to leave it to a set theorist to write a better answer than I could.

Comment: I don’t think there are any active set theorists left on this site. So any answer, even if not from a set theorist would be helpful.(Of course if you have the time)

Comment: Or maybe you could advise me, if I should move the question to MO?  Where I think a few set theorists are remaining.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku Asaf Karagila, Andres Caicedo, Joel David Hamkins, Andreas Blass, and Noah Schweber (to name a few of the top posters in the set-theory tag) all remain active here as far as I know. I think your question could be a good fit for MO, especially if you emphasize the aspect of working without Replacement.